Error: Module "3" is missing from the asset registry when loading fonts
I'm trying to load some fonts here and can't get rid of that error:
import { useFonts } from "expo-font";
import { Stack, SplashScreen } from "expo-router";
import { useEffect } from "react";

SplashScreen.preventAutoHideAsync();

const RootLayout = () => {
  const [fontsLoaded, error] = useFonts({
    "Poppins-Black": require("../assets/fonts/Poppins-Black.ttf"),
    "Poppins-Bold": require("../assets/fonts/Poppins-Bold.ttf"),
    "Poppins-ExtraBold": require("../assets/fonts/Poppins-ExtraBold.ttf"),
    "Poppins-ExtraLight": require("../assets/fonts/Poppins-ExtraLight.ttf"),
    "Poppins-Light": require("../assets/fonts/Poppins-Light.ttf"),
    "Poppins-Medium": require("../assets/fonts/Poppins-Medium.ttf"),
    "Poppins-Regular": require("../assets/fonts/Poppins-Regular.ttf"),
    "Poppins-SemiBold": require("../assets/fonts/Poppins-SemiBold.ttf"),
    "Poppins-Thin": require("../assets/fonts/Poppins-Thin.ttf"),
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    if (error) {
      console.log("Font Loading Error:", error); // Log the specific error
      throw error;
    }

    if (fontsLoaded) {
      console.log("Fonts Loaded Successfully!");
      SplashScreen.hideAsync();
    }
  }, [fontsLoaded, error]);

  if (!fontsLoaded) {
    return null;
  }

  if (!fontsLoaded && !error) {
    return null;
  }

  return (
    <Stack>
      <Stack.Screen name="(tabs)" options={{ headerShown: false }} />
      <Stack.Screen name="(auth)" options={{ headerShown: false }} />
      <Stack.Screen name="index" options={{ headerShown: false }} />
      <Stack.Screen name="search/[query]" options={{ headerShown: false }} />
    </Stack>
  );
};

export default RootLayout;

Here's the package.json:
{
  "name": "aora",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "expo-router/entry",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.24.4",
    "@react-native/assets-registry": "0.75.0-main",
    "expo": "~50.0.17",
    "expo-constants": "~15.4.6",
    "expo-font": "^11.10.3",
    "expo-linking": "~6.2.2",
    "expo-router": "~3.4.8",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.11.1",
    "nativewind": "^2.0.11",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.73.6",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.8.2",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.29.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.24.4",
    "tailwindcss": "3.3.2"
  },
  "private": true
}

Also, project structure and app.json:
root -> assets -> fonts
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "Aora",
    "slug": "aora",
    "scheme": "aora",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./assets/icon.png",
    "userInterfaceStyle": "light",
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/splash.png",
      "resizeMode": "contain",
      "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
    },
    "assetBundlePatterns": [
      "./assets/**/*.{ttf,png}"
    ],
    "ios": {
      "supportsTablet": true
    },
    "android": {
      "adaptiveIcon": {
        "foregroundImage": "./assets/adaptive-icon.png",
        "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
      }
    },
    "web": {
      "favicon": "./assets/favicon.png"
    },
    "plugins": [
      "expo-router"
    ]
  }
}


I've tried cleaning and rebuilding, uninstalling the @react-native/assets-registry package to see if it was a conflict with native Expo asset loading features, but it's an essencial package to the project. Can anyone help me with this?

After you updated to a new SDK you have to update other packages too.
Expo's warning message
npm install expo-constants@16.0.1 expo-font@12.0.5 expo-linking@6.3.1 expo-router@3.5.11 expo-status-bar@1.12.1 react-native@0.74.1 react-native-safe-area-context@4.10.1 react-native-screens@3.31.1 typescript@5.3.3

Your answer is similar to what Eldin typed below, it still gives me the same error after updating...

The paths in useFonts look off by one level. Can you try this instead
  const [fontsLoaded, error] = useFonts({
    "Poppins-Black": require("./assets/fonts/Poppins-Black.ttf"),
    "Poppins-Bold": require("./assets/fonts/Poppins-Bold.ttf"),
    "Poppins-ExtraBold": require("./assets/fonts/Poppins-ExtraBold.ttf"),
    "Poppins-ExtraLight": require("./assets/fonts/Poppins-ExtraLight.ttf"),
    "Poppins-Light": require("./assets/fonts/Poppins-Light.ttf"),
    "Poppins-Medium": require("./assets/fonts/Poppins-Medium.ttf"),
    "Poppins-Regular": require("./assets/fonts/Poppins-Regular.ttf"),
    "Poppins-SemiBold": require("./assets/fonts/Poppins-SemiBold.ttf"),
    "Poppins-Thin": require("./assets/fonts/Poppins-Thin.ttf"),
  });

And I haven't seen that kind of regex in assetBundlePatterns, maybe change it to this as well?
    "assetBundlePatterns": [
      "./assets/**/*.ttf",
      "./assets/**/*.png"
    ],

Let me know if that worked for you

The path was autocompleted, I'm pretty sure it's right. If I change it as you said I get "Unable to resolve "./assets/fonts/Poppins-Black.ttf" from "app_layout.jsx"". About the assetBundlePatterns, I just double checked it and it's fine, the error persists

I think you are following JavaScript Mastery course and now you have updated your project to a new SDK, right?
You can try Remove node modules and installing them once again.
rm -rf node_modules
bun install expo@latest
bunx expo install --fix


Followed your steps, which I believe is similar to Mzato suggestion above, and the error persists! And yes, it's from JSM hehe

try next:

clean cache of you package manager, I use bun for me it bun pm cache rm
delete node_modules folder
bun install && bun expo install --fix
clean metro bundler cache rm -rf $TMPDIR/metro-cache
generate you native code bun expo prebuild --platform ios --clean


Followed your guide step by step and the error persisted. It's really annoying, I can tell you that hahah

I'm running into the same problem. I'm following the same tutorial from Javascript Mastery too.
But I solved mine with changing package manager from pnpm into yarn.

remove node_modules
remove package-lock.json
remove packageManager: "pnpm..." inside package.json`
run yarn install or npm install

